# How to get error output when ansible.systemd fails with restart?

Tags: error-handling, ansible, systemd, restart

With the following ansible:

```
- name: Reload changes in configuration and restart docker service
  systemd:
    name: docker
    enabled: true
    daemon_reload: true
    state: restarted
    register: command_output
- name: Print to console
  debug:
    msg: "{{command_output.stdout}}"
```

I see the following error:

> fatal: [xxxxxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to start
> service docker: Job for docker.service failed because the control
> process exited with error code.\nSee "systemctl status
> docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.\n"}

This is of course a very useful error message when on the command line, but in **ansible**, not so much. My attempt at capturing the error output and dispalying it in debug has not been very fruitful. So the question is:

**How can I get more details about the reason why `ansible.systemd` failed in this case?**

Should I try to invoke `journalctl -xe` or `systemctl status docker.service` manually, or is there some other more ansible friendly way?

Comment: You won't get "more" from the `systemd` task Ansible is already returning your the stderr of the command, like it would in a terminal, indeed.

Comment: What you can try, still, to be sure of my above assumptions is to add a `failed_when: false` to the `systemd` task, then your debug will kick in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever ansible module capture is already there stderr or stdout return values.. If you want to get more details of the error, you can try Block and Rescue ... [Block and Resuce Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html)

```
block:
  - name: Reload changes in configuration and restart docker service
    systemd:
      name: docker
      enabled: true
      daemon_reload: true
      state: restarted
      register: command_output
  - name: Print to console
    debug:
      msg: "{{command_output.stdout}}"
rescue:
  - name: get errors
    shell: journalctl -xe  # or systemctl status docker.service
    register: err_msg
  - name: Print error message to console
    debug:
      msg: "{{ err_msg.stdout }}"
```